# MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION is available or not

Tags: android, api, voice-recognition, android-hardware, noise-reduction

I'm working on a project in which I have to use an Android Development Board, just like following, to record audio via MIC, specifically speech.

- [PandaBoard](http://pandaboard.org/content/resources/references)
- [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/Products/BeagleBone%20Black)
- [AM335x Evaluation Module](http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxevm3358)

For my audio, from MIC, I want it to be filtered with background noise. I know I can apply some noise suppression algorithms to filter it but I want to use the built-in feature **VOICE_RECOGNITION** as audio source, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_RECOGNITION), to filter background noise.

```
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT, minBufSize);
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT, minBufSize);
```

> [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_RECOGNITION), **VOICE_RECOGNITION** says:
>
> Microphone audio source tuned for voice recognition if available, behaves like DEFAULT otherwise.

It says **'if available'**, it make sense that this feature is not available in all devices neither it is an Android OS part because if it is a part of OS, it should be available in all devices. It means, it is something related to hardware and all the manufacturer probably are not providing this feature.

My questions:

1. How I can know whether this feature is available or not before I go for purchase?
2. Is this feature is really related to hardware, as I assumed?
3. If this feature is not available in my respective device, How I can bring it on ?

NOTE: All the Android Development Boards, defined above, can run Android JellyBean 4.2.2.

NOTE: I have Samsung Galaxy S2 and this feature is available in it. Tested, works fine.

Any extra details would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: do you think to use google api to voice recognition?

Comment: yes, this is my plan but before that I'm more focused on noise suppression.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is the noise cancellation is achieved by utilising a 2nd dedicated mic which captures the ambient noise seperately. I believe the hardware related requirement is the presence of this dedicated mic.

Looking at tech specs for the Galaxy S2 you can see the feature noted as:

> *Active noise cancellation with dedicated mic*

source: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9100_galaxy_s_ii-3621.php

As another example, the Nexus 5 mentions in the tech specs:

> *Dual microphones*

source: https://www.google.com.au/nexus/5/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VOICE_RECOGNITION has the **least** (often no) pre-processing. The default MIC input has the built-in processing.

Comment: Can anyone back it up with a reference?